# Update a ListBoxFrom a Background Thread in MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, windows-phone-8, mvvm

I have a ListBox in my View that is DataBinded to an ObservableCollection in my ViewModel.But my View is not updating even after I load the data in my ViewModel

I use this delegate to load the data for the list :

```
public ObservableCollection<TwitterElement_> MyCollection_
{
    get;
    private set;
}

[...]
public MainViewModel()
{
   this.MyList_ = new List<Object>();
   this.MyCollection_ = new ObservableCollection<Object>();

   this.loadedCommand = new RelayCommand(async() =>
   {
     this.MyList_=  await  FirstLoad();
     foreach (Element_ t in MyList_) 
     {
        this.MyCollection_.Add(t); 
     }
   });
}

public async Task<List<Object>> FirstLoad() 
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<List<Object>>();
    var client = new RestSharp.RestClient("https://Example.com");

    var request = new RestSharp.RestRequest("/request", Method.GET);


    client.ExecuteAsync(request, (response) =>
    {
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Task<List<Object>> FirstTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<List<Object>>(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Object>>(response.Content));

            Task<List<Object>> SecondTask = FirstTask.ContinueWith((ft) =>
            {

            //Operations That I removed for more clarity...
               [...]
                return ft.Result; 
            });
            tcs.SetResult(SecondTask.Result);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    });
    return await tcs.Task;
}
```

But My ListBox is not Updating with the data even though I transfer the object from the List to the ObservableCollection which is supposed to act on the UI thread what should I do?

Comment: Can you show your XAML where you are binding?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your collection bound to the `ListBox` with `Binding` or are you setting `ItemsSource` property manually?

If it is done with `Binding`, you need to set `DataContext` of the page that has `ListBox` to your view model. `DataContext = [instance of MainViewModel]`

Comment: I use the MVVMight Toolkit Binding is done this way  : DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

Comment: And Locator is instance of your main view model right? It looks like it should just work. Maybe there is typo somewhere in your XAML?

Comment: I have checked again and the typo is right everywhere in my xaml